# ImportError on Heroku django-registration-redux

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-registration

I have no problem with my apps when it's running locally. But it's happen on heroku. I was successfully deployed my app to heroku but when I open it (My `DEBUG` still `TRUE`) it was give me `ImportError No module named forms` comes from `from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail`. I have confusing bout that because when I start `heroku run python manage.py shell` and doing import `from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail` it's nothing error.

[image]

urls.py

```
from myapp.forms import CustomRegistrationForm
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^register/$', logout_required(RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=CustomRegistrationForm)), name='registration_register'),
     url(r'^', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
]
```

myapp/forms.py

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
from .validators import ForbiddenUsernamesValidator

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].validators.append(ForbiddenUsernamesValidator)
```

myapp/validators.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def ForbiddenUsernamesValidator(value):
    forbidden_usernames = ['admin', 'settings', 'news', 'about', 'help', '........']
    if value.lower() in forbidden_usernames:
        raise ValidationError('This username is forbidden.')
    if len(value) < 4:
        raise ValidationError('Username must have at least 4 characters.')
```

Here's my app [here](https://glacial-wave-87412.herokuapp.com/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the guide here http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html to install django-registration-redux? Specifically this part:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'registration', #should be immediately above 'django.contrib.auth'
    'django.contrib.auth',
    # ...other installed applications...
)
```

Comment: Yes, I did. My app running with no problem on local... And I still have no idea bout this problem...